# AmCharts Animate Lines on a Map?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

I've been looking to put in an animated map for my website. However, I'm struggling to create some effects that look to have been previously possible in AmCharts, or perhaps even possible but I'm not sure where to go with it.

[image: animated map example]

Compressing the effect down into a gif along with the design of the website was unfortunately not so good, but hopefully you can see the effect I'm attempting to recreate. I noted that one user had used [a method for an older version of AmCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/animating-map-lines-with-css/) to animate the CSS of the path, although this wouldn't exactly accomplish my desired effects.

I just wanted to know if it was at all possible to create this effect in the newer version of AmCharts. I've created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/tonycre8-the-bold/pen/RwezadL) to give a base as to what I've tried. I've had a go at implementing the CSS trick used in prior versions:

```css
#mapdiv path {
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dasharray: 500%;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 /; /* fixes IE prob */
    stroke-dashoffset: 0 /; /* fixes IE prob */
    -webkit-animation: am-draw 40s;
    animation: am-draw 40s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes am-draw {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 500%;
        fill: red;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
        fill: blue;
    }
}
@keyframes am-draw {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 500%;
        fill: red;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
        fill: blue;
    }
}
```

But unfortunately to no avail. It seems to just ignore the CSS code. I did also try adding some of the functions like setting the line id, but that seemed to break the code since it appears to be old syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The amCharts site has a demo that appears to do what you are looking for with the animated lines and using amCharts 5. Animations there seem to be all coded in the javascript portion rather than any css.
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-with-animated-lines/